# Strange Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
var_dump($ExtraColumns);
var_dump(is_array($ExtraColumns) );
foreach ($ExtraColumns as $key => $value) {
    $aColumns = array_push($aColumns, $value[1]);           
}
```

[image]

I don't understand this error, because var is an array and not empty, but this error appears!

Comment: Is that the same line the foreach is on? There seems to be no reason it would not work

Comment: Are you sure *this* is the `foreach` it's complaining about?  Are you sure that's line 617?

Comment: Have you tried typecasting to array: $ExtraColumns = (array)$ExtraColumns;. Is it possible the $ExtraColumns is an object that implements Iterator?

Comment: @VladCazacu: His `is_array` is returning `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this line of code should not work:

```
$aColumns = array_push($aColumns, $value[1]);
```

array_push() returns integer and gets array as a first parameter..

Comment: Since this is accepted, he probably had a foreach dealing with $aColumns

Comment: Yes, i think so too.. because the original error was in the foreach.